# Copy a storage file within a Firebase Cloud Function

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

I am launching a cloud function in order to replicate one register I have in Firestore. One of the fields is an image, and the function first tries to copy the image and then duplicate the register.

This is the code:

```
export async function copyContentFunction(data: any, context: any): Promise<String> {
  if (!context.auth || !context.auth.token.isAdmin) {
    throw new functions.https.HttpsError('unauthenticated', 'Auth error.');
  }

  const id = data.id;
  const originalImage = data.originalImage;
  const copy = data.copy;

  if (id === null || originalImage === null || copy === null) {
    throw new functions.https.HttpsError('invalid-argument', 'Missing mandatory parameters.');
  }

  console.log(`id: ${id}, original image: ${originalImage}`);

  try {
    // Copy the image
    await admin.storage().bucket('content').file(originalImage).copy(
      admin.storage().bucket('content').file(id)
    );

    // Create new content
    const ref = admin.firestore().collection('content').doc(id);
    await ref.set(copy);

    return 'ok';
  } catch {
    throw new functions.https.HttpsError('internal', 'Internal error.');
  }
}
```

I have tried multiple combinations but this code always fail. For some reason the process of copying the image is failing, I am doing anything wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: What is `copy` in `await ref.set(copy);`? Also, can you share the **entire** code of your Cloud Function as well as the error you get?

Comment: @RenaudTarnec I have updated the question with the full function code. 'copy' is the document to add to firestore.

Comment: Can you log the error in the catch block? `catch(error) {…}`. Also, is the `content` bucket existing?

Comment: Now that you mention it, I wasn't understanding how buckets work. I have set the correct bucket name and everything worked ok, thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using the `copy()` method in a Cloud Function should work without problem. You don't share any detail about the error you get (I recommend to use `catch(error)` instead of just `catch`) but I can see two potential problems with your code:

- The file corresponding to `originalImage` does not exist;
- The `content` bucket does not exists in your Cloud Storage instance.

The second problem usually comes from the common mistake of mixing up the concepts of **buckets** and **folders** (or directories) in Cloud Storage.

Actually Google Cloud Storage does not have genuine "folders". In the Cloud Storage console, the files in your bucket are presented in a hierarchical tree of folders (just like the file system on your local hard disk) but this is just a way of presenting the files: there aren't genuine folders/directories in a bucket. The Cloud Storage console just uses the different parts of the file paths to "simulate" a folder structure, by using the "/" delimiter character.

This [doc](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/addlhelp/HowSubdirectoriesWork) on Cloud Storage and `gsutil` explains and illustrates very well this "illusion of a hierarchical file tree".

So, if you want to copy a file from your default bucket to a content "folder", do as follows:

```
await admin.storage().bucket().file(`content/${originalImage}`).copy(
  admin.storage().bucket().file(`content/${id}`)
);
```